# wordpress index.php doesn't open locally

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, localhost, mamp

I using MAMP to start creating wordpress themes.
MAMP, WP and DB created are fine.

I have got my index.php and style.css already in my theme folder and I can see the new theme created in there. But when I try to preview my code using localhost I am not getting any result.

When i try to open my wordpress theme on a local host (MAMP) the site doesn't open, what opens is a list of what's in the directory, clicking on the index.php does the same. Admin site works fine. Not sure what the problem is.

Every other local site (not wordpress) works fine

Any clue?
Kind Regards
Fábio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a page called front-page.php, put some text in there and see if that shows

Comment: Hi Bryony, thanks for your quick response. I have just done what you suggested and it works. For some reason index.php doesn't work at all. However if I click "visit site" it still takes me bak to the directory list. All the best.

Comment: Hi Fabio, I am afraid that has never happened to me, and I cant begin to think as to why the inex.php would take you to the directory. Sorry!